# How can I create a login page that logs into another website?

Tags: html, authentication

I have a login url that a client doesn't want to use, instead they would like to have their own login page that logs into the existing webpage without the existing webpage being seen.

The exiting url is https://diamond.realtimedespatch.co.uk/web/user/login.htm

The client wants their own logo's shown on their own login page.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem correctly, you need to use SSO ( Single singn on) on your project. You will get more details for SSO at https://auth0.com/docs/sso/single-sign-on

Comment: Different login page is easy. But what do you mean by " logs into the existing webpage without the existing webpage being seen." Are you talking about what shows up after the user has logged on?  Or is it just a customized logon page?